Is there any way to add another URL to CORS for Power Portal Private Mode?
I have a private access portal that my users are able to authenticate into. It works fine, but the problem is that I have my logins running against a different URL (using Azure B2C), and users aren't able to access the portal from B2C (it gives a CORS error when it tries to access login.windows.net to verify that the user has access).
I'm just wondering if there's any way of configuring the Power Platform login so that I can access it from both of those URLs? It would need to support the portal itself, as well as the B2C authentication link.
Tried looking around to see if I can find any documentation for this, couldn't find anything. As far as I can tell there isn't any way to go into the login.windows.net for messing around in the headers.
I came up with a work around of instead of having B2C request to the private portal, we'd request to a separate portal (one that's set up to be public, and only hosts the web pages without any user data). Reason I'd prefer to avoid that is because there'd be a lot of additional work setting it up and hosting another environment, which would be ideal if we can avoid.
